# How to implement a search in multiple fields based on condition(s)

Tags: java, hibernate, if-statement, conditional-statements, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to implement a Hibernate Full Text Search. The user can choose, which fields are relevant for the search or not. This is done by six (my example) boolean checkboxes in JSF.

Six booleans mean 2^6 possible combinations. I need to map all those conditions.

Example:

```
boolean a;
boolean b;
boolean c;
boolean d;
boolean e;
boolean f;

if(a){
// do a search with a 
}

..

if(a && b){
// do a search with a and b only
}

..

if(a && b && c){
// do a search with a and b and c only
}
```

In every IF-Statement, a method should be called.

Particlularly example based on my case:

A user wants to search users with surname and/or givenname.

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
                    .onFields("user.surname", "user.givenname")
                    .matching(searchstring).createQuery();
```

Conditonally:

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(BeitragVO.class).get();

if(user){
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
                        .onFields("user.surname", "user.givenname")
                        .matching(searchstring).createQuery();
}

if(company){
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
                        .onField("company.name")
                        .matching(searchstring).createQuery();
}

   if(student && company){

    // How can I add all relevant fields(givenname, surname, and name of     
    company) to the query?
    }
```

Is there a way to do it better as 64 IF's ?

Comment: What does `// do a search with a and b and c only` actually look like?

Comment: You should encapsulate "do a search with `a`" into some sort of `A` object. Then use a `Set` of `SearchCriterion` or something along those lines.

Comment: I updated my question aswell. I really missed this point, thank you @AnthonyGrist

Comment: Alexander, I guess it was my mistake trying to amend my question to show you how to accomplish your goal by trying to write code. So, I removed my answer with all those amendments and replaced it with my original answer with just one amendment tying my answer to lucene.  This answer stands as it is.  You can wait and see if someone else posts an answer which provides you with the actual runnable code that you need.

Comment: No problem Mike. I still guess, you did not get my point. But nevermind! I'm really glad, that you did your best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate this, I see this often, but I guess my point was not clear enough, so I will answer my question on my own, sorry!

A friend of mine asked me: "Can't you use a list of fields, instead of passing them seriatim?

Well, I checked this and it is possible to give `onFields()` a array of Strings (thanks to varargs (...)).

I added all my fields to a list and pass them as param to my the method. Based on the given conditions, it is possible to add fields (or not).

Example:

```
List<BeitragVO> results;

    List<String> fields= new ArrayList<String>();

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
            .getFullTextEntityManager(em); // em = entitymanager



    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(BeitragVO.class).get();

    if (student) {
        fields.add("user.surname");
        fields.add("user.givenname");
    }
    if (company) {
        fields.add("company.name");
    }


    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
            .onFields(fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]))
            .matching(searchterm).createQuery();
```

If company AND students are true, the search is using all three fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code like this:

```
String search = "";

if(a){
    search += ...
}

..

if(b){
    search += ...
}

..

if(c){
    search += ...
}
```

Just add any SQL query (criteria) code by the selection it self by each checkbox, and then run it

Comment: This was indeed really helpful, but unfortunately not my point, sorry. Still vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate searches are best done with criteria queries. (Look them up.) In criteria queries you construct the query piece by piece. So, you would end up having something like this:

```
create criteria query
add non-changing criteria query parts (like where to search, what to retrieve)
if( a ) add criteria query term for a
if( b ) add criteria query term for b
...
execute query
```

EDIT: the same principle applies to Lucene Queries.